# How to display gauge needle in android at starting of activity

Tags: android, gauge

I am creating an application that consists of analog gauge i downloaded from [here](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/GaugeView) .When i click the button the needle will deflect to the value. But in my application, When i start the application needle was disappeared. When i clicked button then the needle comes to appear and starts to deflect, i want to appear the needle at the starting of the application
 this is my java code:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Evelina Vrabie
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *******************************************************************************/
package org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo;

import java.util.Random;
import org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GaugeView mGaugeView1;
    Button check;
    private final Random RAND = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGaugeView1 = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view1);
        check = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            mTimer.start();

        }
    });
    }

    public  final CountDownTimer mTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished) {
            mGaugeView1.setTargetValue((float)25.0);
            //mGaugeView2.setTargetValue(RAND.nextInt(101));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {}
    };
}
```

this is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.demo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <org.codeandmagic.android.gauge.GaugeView
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="303dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show needle at the start of the application...in onCreate() method call

```
mGaugeView1.setTargetValue(0);
```

after initializing the mGaugeView1.

Comment: Thanks dude it helped me a lot  mGaugeView1.setTargetValue(0);  @Chandrakanth